# How to hyphenate texts on the command line

Tags: bash, shell, text-formatting, latex, text-processors

I want to split the content of a text file into its syllables (or I simply want to hyphenate it; I don't want to get into the scientifically/lingualistically correct details like here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133859/using-tex-to-split-words-into-syllables).

So if I have a text like

> syllable breaking algorithm

I want it to be broken down to

> syl-la-ble break-ing al-go-rithm

Now, I know (la)tex is able to do this somehow with the `\showhyphens{syllable breaking algorithm}` command, which gives its result in the tex log. However, I'd like to batch this and want to be able to concatenate the results with other text manipulating commands. So I don't want to create a tex-project and scan the log everytime I have to hyphenate the text.

Thus my question is, is there a straight forward way to hyphenate a text? Something like

```
hyphenate my-text-file.txt
```

I could also live with an approach that uses the Latex infrastructure.

## My approach

So what I've done so far is building my own library of hyphenatable words that appeared in my target text. I guess this problem would already be solved if one could get such a library for "all" words there are.

```
text=$1

declare -A hyphens
hyphens=(["serem"]="se+rem" ["serer"]="se+rer" ["Jeder"]="Je+der" ["Gehen"]="Ge+hen" ["berühmten"]="be+rühm+ten" ["Gefühlen"]="Ge+füh+len" ["Leben"]="Le+ben" ["seinen"]="sei+nen" ["zügeln"]="zü+geln" ["lassen"]="las+sen" ["allem"]="al+lem" ["draußen"]="draus+sen" ["seinem"]="sei+nem" ["kalten"]="kal+ten" ["diese"]="die+se" ["gestellt"]="ge+stellt" ["seine"]="sei+ne" ["Gegen"]="Ge+gen" ["nächstes"]="näch+stes" ["Allein"]="Al+lein")
for hyphen in "${!hyphens[@]}"
do
        sed -i "s/$hyphen/${hyphens[$hyphen]}/g" "$text"
done
cat "$text"
```

Comment: Have you tried something to get some results ? What you are asking for is not that simple. I will suggest to switch to perl and use a library called : Lingua-EN-Syllable.

Comment: @RedaSalih My use case was creating a txt file for Ultra Star Deluxe. In the mean time I found https://github.com/UltraStar-Deluxe/UltraStar-Creator This is a tool, which features the ability to automatically hyphenate a given text. So while this isn't a cli tool, which would be pipable, it is a usable work around for me. Since that isn't the answer to this question, I will still leave it open. I will edit my cli approach to the question.

Comment: That means that you have solved the problem if you have a fixed array, or it's just an example ?

Comment: @RedaSalih It's a workaround for my question. If I had a library for all words and their syllables, the work around would be usable.